# SQL Server - Select statement include Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is this correct way to use variable and finally display how many records in between Vol1 >0 and vol1 <=10.

```
declare @x int;
set @x=0;
select
    case when vol1 > 0 and vol1 <=10 then x = x + 1 end
from coverage
group by vol1
print @x
```

Comment: SQL is Set based. So you don't do loops like code unless there is no choice at all (which would be very rare).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to assign the variable in the `select` and get rid of the `group by`, so the query only returns one row:

```
declare @x int;
set @x = 0;

select @x = count(*)
from coverage
where vol1 > 0 and vol1 <= 10;

print @x;
```